# Remove Files file-manager without losing my Personal Folder

Tags: 13.04, filemanager

I am very unhappy with Files, which replaced Nautilus in 13.04 as the default file manager.

How can I replace it with a better file manager without losing my Personal Folder?

Answer (score 0):

You won't and you do not need to remove it to use another file manager.

Do not know if you can remove it from your system without breaking anything, maybe a better option is to just install another file-manager of your choice and use it instead?

Install another that you might want to use, ie: dolphin, and replace it as your default file handler using `dconf-editor`.

Another good and easy option for that is to edit `/usr/local/bin/nautilus` and replace the lines

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/Nautilus $@
```

with

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/foo_filemanager $@
```

this way every time a process calls for Nautilus it will call your new file-manager instead.

Comment: I use Raring. My directory /usr/local/bin/ does not have a link to nautilus. Should I create it? The program nautilus is in usr/bin.

Comment: sec, checking now, this was made from head